# Tableau install AWS found only 0 GB for the data directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tableau-api, amazon-ebs

I am creating a Tableau Server self-deployed instance on EC2.

I created the EC2 instance using:

```
resource "aws_instance" "tableau" {
  ami           = "amzn2-ami-hvm-*-x86_64-ebs"
  instance_type = "m5.4xlarge"
  vpc_security_group_ids = var.sg
  subnet_id = var.private_subnet
  associate_public_ip_address = false
  key_name = var.key_name

  tags = {
    Name = var.namespace
  }
}
```

The instance is working fine and once I logged in I did:

```
#Download tableau installer

wget https://downloads.tableau.com/esdalt/2021.1.2/tableau-server-2021-1-2.x86_64.rpm

#Install tableau

sudo yum update
sudo yum install tableau-server-2021-1-2.x86_64.rpm

#Initialize TSM

cd /opt/tableau/tableau_server/packages/scripts.20211.21.0511.0935

sudo ./initialize-tsm --accepteula --accepteula -f
```

This last statement returns:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    WARNING: Tableau Server requires at least 15 GB of free disk space to run,
    but found only 0 GB for the data directory '/var/opt/tableau/tableau_server'.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

Starting TSM services...
No se pudo realizar la operación.
Se ha producido un error durante la instalación.
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoAuthException: KeeperErrorCode = NoAuth for /tableau/tabsvc-clusterid/ports
ERROR: TSM services returned status 10
```

The volume is:

```
df -hT

S.ficheros     Tipo     Tamaño Usados  Disp Uso% Montado en
devtmpfs       devtmpfs    32G      0   32G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs       32G   4,0K   32G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs       32G   560K   32G   1% /run
tmpfs          tmpfs       32G      0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p1 xfs        8,0G   7,6G  452M  95% /
tmpfs          tmpfs      6,3G      0  6,3G   0% /run/user/0
tmpfs          tmpfs      6,3G      0  6,3G   0% /run/user/995
tmpfs          tmpfs      6,3G      0  6,3G   0% /run/user/1000
```

I tried creating a new volume for the specific path `/var/opt/tableau` but terraform returns an error as `device_name` is not valid due it is the `/var` path.

I don't find how to add extra size for this specific and default path for tableau install. I would like to use default path to avoid extra setup for users, and others if I install the Tableau server in a different path.

Any idea how to add the `/var` path to the EBS volume?

Answer (score 1):

I created the volume with more GB and its fixes, one of the tmpfs is where `/var` is located at.